# Fedora 8/EC2: ld cannot find library

Tags: gcc, amazon-ec2, fedora, ld

I'm trying to get gcc to work on an Amazon EC2 image of Fedora 8, but I'm running into an issue with the libraries.  ld is not finding -lz -lm -lbz2.

I've tried adding -L /lib and -L /usr/lib to the arguments for gcc, but it is still not working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Where are the libraries located? Did you locate the libs at the paths you are using with the `-L` option?

Comment: The libs are in /usr/bin as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Dave -  How can you specify libs in /usr/bin?
-L/lib and -L/usr/lib tells the compiler to fetch the libraries from these locations which you are specifying using -l option.
/usr/bin doesn't have libraries considering the naming of the folders. 
However if you have a lib in that in extreme case, you may want to use the compilation option -L/usr/bin. This is strange solution for me considering i have never seen libs at this location let alone use it.